# Is there a way to open a modal directly from a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have seen and have many examples of opening a modal on a ng-click but can I open a modal on the resolution of a `$http` get request? I have a plunker that I am trying to get the general idea here http://plnkr.co/edit/1XJUAP.

Comment: You're probably better off creating a modal service with an error and success function that creating separate controllers.

Comment: Hmm, that makes a lot of sense. Then I don't have to worry about the scope of the controllers and I can just inject the modal service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by setting a call to your open() function in the success handler for the $http request

```
$http.get(url).success(function(data){ $scope.open();});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the original question but I am going to try to utilize a modal service example.